# Django 1.10 Translation

Tags: python, django, translation

I was trying internationalization/localization in django.
I am getting an error while i am trying to make the '.po' files using the command

> ./manage.py makemessages

relevant parts from settings.py

```
import os

from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'sampleproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.i18n'
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'sampleproject.wsgi.application'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('fi-FI', _('Finnish')),
    ('en', _('English')),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale'),
]
```

relevant parts from urls.py

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    url(r'^$', home, name='home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
)
```

here is the traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 305, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 356, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 361, in handle
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 393, in build_potfiles
    self.process_files(file_list)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 488, in process_files
    self.process_locale_dir(locale_dir, files)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 507, in process_locale_dir
    build_file.preprocess()
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 113, in preprocess
    content = templatize(src_data, self.path[2:])
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 214, in templatize
    return _trans.templatize(src, origin)
  File "/project/Myapps/for_sample/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py", line 670, in templatize
    "%s (%sline %d)" % (t.contents, filemsg, t.lineno)
SyntaxError: Translation blocks must not include other block tags: blocktrans count var|length as count (file htmlcov/_project_Myapps_for_sample_lib_python3_4_site-packages_django_templatetags_i18n_py.html, line 1073)
```

Dev Setup:
Django 1.10
Python 3.4.5

As this is my first question in SO, pardon me if there's any mistake :)
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does your `htmlcov/_project_Myapps_for_sample_lib_python3_4_site-packages_django_templatetags_i18n_py.html` html-template look like? It says error is there.

Comment: Yea.. i just resolved the error. That file mentioned was generated when i run the coverage.py script.. i deleted the html reports and the error is gone.. but no .po files are generated again when running ./manage.py makemessages command.

Comment: Run with `--keep-pot` option. It "prevents deleting the temporary .pot files generated before creating the .po file. This is useful for debugging errors which may prevent the final language files from being created." https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#makemessages

Comment: Yea.. it worked.. thanks mate :)

Comment: FYI - you posted your SECRET_KEY to the world. You *never* want to let your secret key get out. I'm guessing this isn't production, but you should still change it. Philip James gave a nice 5-minute lightning talk at DjangoCon US on what to do: https://speakerdeck.com/phildini/oops-i-committed-my-secret-key

Comment: Its just a sample app i did to try out coverage, translation and sphinx.. well, i have removed the secret key as per your suggestion...
 thanks for the info FlipperPA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurred because of the htmlcov folder which was generated while running the coverage script.

Removed that folder and executed the following commands to generate the '.po' files.

> ./manage.py makemessages -l fi

and the following command to generate the '.mo' files.

> ./manage.py compilemessages